# Check if Textbox contains numbers & other invalid characters

Tags: c#

How do I check to see if a textbox contains characters that a user entered that I don't want the program to accept? Numbers and other sorts like !@#$[] etc. This is for when the user clicks a button and if an invalid character is present an error message will pop up.

```
private void btnAddSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtAddEmployerName.Text.Contains  //INVALID CHARACTERS GO HERE)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You may only enter letters", "Error");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily using Regular Expression. This will validate user input to check alphabets only.

```
private void btnAddSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtAddEmployerName.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]*$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You may only enter letters", "Error");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the mask should be `^[a-zA-Z ]*$` - the *entire* (`^...$`) string contains of any number (`*`) of letters or spaces. Your current implementation means "string starts from space or a..zA..Z letter"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for drawing my attention. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *Linq* which is quite direct: if `txtAddEmployerName.Text` contains `Any` character which is not *space* or *letter* show error:

```
 private void btnAddSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // char.IsLetter - any unicode letter, not necessary English ones 
   // e.g. Russian (Cyrillic) are included as well: Это тоже буквы
   // In case you want a..z A..Z only
   //   c => c == '' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'
   if (txtAddEmployerName.Text.Any(c => !(c == ' ' || char.IsLetter(c)))) {
     // Let's highlight (i.e. put keyboard focus) on the problem control
     if (txtAddEmployerName.CanFocus)
       txtAddEmployerName.Focus();

     MessageBox.Show("Letters only, please.", "Error");

     return; // seems redundant unless you have more code after the if 
   } 
 }
```